# JavaScript ExtJS - Access Handling with Privileges

Tags: web-applications, extjs4, privileges

i am planning a WebApplication. Using ExtJS to build my frontend and an ASP WebService for the Backend. Communicating via json..

Though there is one big questionmark in my mind. 
I have multiple views with different usercontrols available for different kind of people.
e.g. Only a Superior can see this button etc etc.. 
I have my privileges implemented in my backend but whats the best way to communicate to the view which button i should display and which not. I cant just send a request for single every control which isnt available for everyone i guess this would be fosy :D ..

If you got experience with this issue, please let me know!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've dealt with this issue more than once. I personally like to implement roles in the client-side too. Make some kind of manager which keeps the current role and privileges which come with that role. In your views you can simply ask the manager whether the current user is authorized to see particular controls.

I normally keep all different roles in some kind of enum-like structure (Basically just a javascript array :P)

Comment: so building a js privilege-manager (mapping all the backend privileges) via prebuild command and request the privileges @login is a nice way2go?

Comment: It depends, i usually have the whole thing semi-hard-coded because all my apps are native. This raises some problems with offline-compatibility. Whenever a user logs in the server returns his role.